Embedding of a cyclic group of order $n=2^r$ inside $A_{n+1}$
I'm looking for a proof regarding the following question.

If $r\geq1$ be a positive integer and $n=2^r$ then prove that a cyclic group of order n cannot be embedded inside the Alternating group $A_{n+1}$.

I proceed with the following idea:
Let G be such cyclic group of order $n=2^r$. Then  there exists some elements $\sigma \in G$ of order n whose image under the embedding
,say $f(\sigma)$ has the same order inside $A_{n+1}$. But $A_{n+1}$ consists even permutations on the set of $n+1$ elements which is clear odd here. But how it leads to a contradiction that I don't know.
Any help will be appreciated.
Edit: Previously,I was not very precise about the question,so I made an edit to be precise about the problem.

Hint: What can you say about the cycle type of a generator for the cyclic group?

@Milten So the order of the image of a generator inside $A_{n+1}$ is $2^r$. Therefore $A_{n+1}$ contains a permutations of order $2^r$. And then? Ummm, maybe it's something to do with the fact that since n is even, n+1 is odd here. I don't get it exactly.

Another hint. You can embed this cyclic group into $A_{n+2}$ but not into $A_{n+1}$. Try with $n=4$ first, if you don't see it. If that's difficult, try $n=2$ first.

An element of order $n=2^r$ in $S_{n+1}$ is necessarily an $n$-cycle, hence an odd permutation.
Edit. It is necessarily an $n$-cycle because it is a product of disjoint cycles with lengths $n_1\le\dots\le n_s$ such that $\sum_in_i=2^r+1$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(n_1,\dots,n_s)=2^r$, which implies $n_s=2^r,s=2,n_1=1.$

Can you please elaborate why in $S_{n+1}$, it's necessarily an n-cycle?

They might have mentioned it,  but it's because of the (disjoint)  cycle decomposition.
